# An alternate for Householder QR linear equation solving for fixed-layout sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, sparse-matrices

This concerns sparse matrices where the sparsity pattern is known beforehand, and where the size is between 5 and up to 50, as the linear solver for a Newton Raphson non linear solver.

For smaller than 5, I use a direct inverse computation, but for problems that are bigger, I currently use a simple dense Householder pivot solver, which get slows really quickly.

I can optimize the layout of the matrix as well, but I'm not sure "usual" sparse matrix solving method could be applied here and if they could be faster than brute-force Householder QR. I feel that knowing the sparsity could be leveraged to solve the problem faster.

Comment: "Householder pivot solver"? I know gaussian pivoting and Householder QR, which one is it? Why do you think "usual" sparse solvers would not work? Have you tried? Also a nice feature of iterative methods is you can reuse the preceding solution as a starting point (likely useful in a process that is supposed to be convergent).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Indeed, Householder QR (using Eigen implementation). I'm not sure because I want something faster than dense, and iterative seems contradictory. Still, if you want to implement a sparse iterative solver for something like 4-5 entries per row and columns, what would you go for?

Comment: Since you are using Eigen: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html

Comment: By the way, I didn't notice the numerical-**optimization** tag: you may have a look at [L-BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) or [sparseLM](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sparseLM/).

Comment: Good pointers, thanks. I usually have only a couple of iterations, but LBFGS may be worth it indeed.